Isolated context does not hide [Re]browser automation
My goal was to apply/run cloud browser Rebrowser as a bot-undetected entity. Initially I've got help from How to fix Runtime.Enable CDP detection of Puppeteer, Playwright and other automation libraries post. It helped me to go with an inital success when testing Rebroswer againts https://bot-detector.rebrowser.net test ground.
I've followed the other tutorial for Rebroser Isolated Context. More tests went succesful, while others did not.
See the code:
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import * as fs from 'fs';
// Or import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core';

// Launch the browser and open a new blank page
const args = puppeteer.defaultArgs().filter(arg => arg !== '--generate-pdf-document-outline');
//console.log("Puppeteer default args:");
//console.log(args);
args.push('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled');
//console.log("Puppeteer modified args:");
//console.log(args);
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ ignoreDefaultArgs: true, args });
const page = await browser.newPage();

// add event listener for window messages (executed in the main context)
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      console.log('[main] msg', event)
      if (!event.data.scriptId || event.data.fromMain) {
        // ignore messages without scriptId and from ourselves (from main context)
        return
      }
  
      const response = {
        scriptId: event.data.scriptId,
        fromMain: true,
      }
      try {
        response.result = eval(event.data.scriptText)
        
      } catch (err) {
        response.error = err.message
      }
  
      window.postMessage(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)))
      })
});
await page.setViewport({width: 700, height: 700});
await page.goto('https://bot-detector.rebrowser.net', { waitUntil: 'load' })

/**** Additional checks ****/
// dummyFn
await page.evaluate(() => window.dummyFn());
// sourceUrlLeak
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('detections-json'));
//mainWorldExecution
//console.log("Checkign 'mainWorldExecution' ");
await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('div'));

const html = await page.content();
if (html){   
var file = 'rebr-isolated-res.html';
fs.writeFile(file, html, err => {
    if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    } else {
    console.log("Result file '" + file + "' is written successfully.")
    }
});
} 


// add a helper that we can reuse (executed in an isolated context)
await page.evaluate(() => {
    // listen for messages from main and emit custom event with a response for a specific scriptId
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      if (!(event.data.scriptId && event.data.fromMain)) {
        // ignore irrelevant messages
        return
      }
      console.log('[isolated] msg', event)
      window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(`scriptId-${event.data.scriptId}`, { detail: event.data }))
    })
  
    // a helper that can be reused in other page.evaluate calls
    window.evaluateMain = (scriptFn) => {
      // generate unique scriptId for each call
      window.evaluateMainScriptId = (window.evaluateMainScriptId || 0) + 1
      const scriptId = window.evaluateMainScriptId
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        // listen for the response
        window.addEventListener(`scriptId-${scriptId}`, (event) => {
          resolve(event.detail)
        }, {
          once: true,
        })
  
        // prepare and send a message for the main context
        let scriptText = scriptFn
        if (typeof scriptText !== 'string') {
          scriptText = `(${scriptText.toString()})()`
        }
        window.postMessage({
          scriptId,
          scriptText,
        })
      })
    }
});

// use our helper to evaluate code in the main context
await page.evaluate(() => window.evaluateMain(() => document.getElementsByClassName('div')));
await browser.close();

Still sourceUrlLeak, mainWorldExecution and runtimeEnableLeak were detected. Any reasons why ? Any tips or hints?
See the html file screen of test page upon the Rebrowser with Puppeteer automatisation:

